How to use .default import with TS?
Can anyone who understands the TS tell me,
import BIP32Factory from 'bip32';
import ECPairFactory from 'ecpair';
console.log(BIP32Factory); // For verification, should return "function"
console.log(ECPairFactory);

in the console:
{ default: [Getter], BIP32Factory: [Getter] }
{ default: [Getter], ECPairFactory: [Getter], networks: [Getter] }

const bip32 = BIP32Factory(ecc);
^

TypeError: BIP32Factory is not a function

Should be:
[Function: BIP32Factory]
[Function: ECPairFactory]

In my project, I get js type: "module". If in another project I do it with commonJS then everything is ok, it is imported as a function, but here I need to access it via .defualt, but in TS I can't access it via .default
How can I fix it? Do I really need to convert the whole project to commonJS or to TS and then to commonJS.
in tsconfig:
"target": "es6",
"module": "ESNext",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,

When I tried to change manually in js file, everything is importing okay.

What happens when you set "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false?

Looks like you should use import { BIP32Factory } from 'bip32'; import { ECPairFactory } from 'ecpair';, not default imports

@Bergi, thank you! I'm certainly not attentive...
